# heroku Rake db:migrate fails - undefined method `pushconfig'

Tags: heroku, rake, migrate

I get the error message below. Any suggestions?

```
undefined method `pushconfig' for #<FirstApp::Application:0x000000027bb658>
```

Answer (score 0):

found the issue. I had a syntax error in the production config file

Comment: please provide more info